# Intellij plugin development, how to prevent an action from occuring, like closing a tab

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

Is this possible?

I need to **subscribe to the event somehow** and possibly return false or similar, i am guessing. I have **no idea how** though.

**What event is that?**

Where do I register it?

Anyone?

**EDIT:**

I have tried this:

```
import com.intellij.openapi.components.ApplicationComponent;
import com.intellij.openapi.editor.impl.EditorComponentImpl;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.AWTEventListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class MyPlugin implements ApplicationComponent {

    static {
        /*MessageBus bus = ApplicationManager.getApplication().get

        MessageBusConnection connection = bus.connect();

        connection.subscribe(AppTopics.FILE_DOCUMENT_SYNC,
            new FileDocumentManagerAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void beforeDocumentSaving(Document document) {
                    // create your custom logic here
                }
            });*/
    }

    private final AWTEventListener listener;

    public MyPlugin() {
        System.out.println("111111111111111111");
        listener = new AWTEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void eventDispatched(AWTEvent event) {

                if ( event instanceof KeyEvent ) {
                    KeyEvent kv = (KeyEvent) event;
                    Component component = kv.getComponent();

                    if ( component instanceof EditorComponentImpl) {
                        EditorComponentImpl cp = (EditorComponentImpl) component;

                    }

                    System.out.println("3333333" + component.getClass());
                }

                System.out.println("aaaaaaa" + event.getClass());

            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public void initComponent() {
        System.out.println("bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    @Override
    public void disposeComponent() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().removeAWTEventListener(listener);
    }

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public String getComponentName() {
        return "temp";
    }

}
```

But it does not work. I get events but the wrong kind.

Comment: There is no API in IntelliJ IDEA that would allow you to prevent closing an editor tab. If you could describe the actual problem you're trying to solve, maybe we could suggest a different approach.

Comment: @yole I already developed a plugin for this. Check it out ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two plugins were developed in the end to accomplish this:

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/space/index?pr=idea&lg=opensource%40momomo.com